# WCF deserialization of Dictionary where Enum type is key

Tags: c#, wcf, dictionary, serialization, enums

I would like to aks you for your help. I have here problem with WCF deserialization of Dictionary where Enum type is used as a key.

I have two data objects:

```
[DataContract] 
public enum MyEnum : int
{
   [EnumMember]
   Value1 = 0,
   [EnumMember]
   Value2 = 1
}
```

and

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(MyEnum))] 
public class ReturnData
{
   [DataMember]
   public IDictionary<Enum, string> codes;
}
```

In fact `ReturnData` class contains more data members but they are not important for my example.

These data objects are returned by method:

```
[OperationContract]
public ReturnData Method1()
{
 ReturnData data = new ReturnData();
 data.codes = new Dictionary<Enum, string>();
 data.codes.Add(MyEnum.Value1, "stringA");

 return data;
}
```

When I call Method1 from client side then next exception is thrown:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:Method1Result. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 522. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Key' contains data of the 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AMService:MyEnum' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'MyEnum' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'

Any idea how to define ReturnData class to solve this problem?

Note: When I change `ReturnData` member `codes` to use as key data type `MyEnum` instead of `Enum` `public IDictionary<MyEnum, string> codes;` then deserialization works correctly and data are transferred from server side to client side without problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Jason! Did you get the answer to this problem? I have the same problem with list and dictionary involved.

Answer (score 3):

At the top of your class add a `KnownType` attribute.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[KnownType(typeof(MyEnum))]
[DataContract]
public class Foo {

}
```

Comment: kime waza thanks for your answer. But If you check my class ReturnData again you can see 'KnownType' attribute is already there...

Comment: yeah did you add that after i did my answer, i didn't see it before?  :) Have you tried regenerating the client proxy with the KnownType attribute in place on the server?

Answer (score 0):

should'nt this line

```
data.codes = new Dictionary<Enum, string>();
```

be

```
data.codes = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>();
```

Comment: No.
It is not possible to compile: IDictionary<Enum, string> codes = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>();

Comment: how about IDictionary<MyEnum, string> codes = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>();

Comment: Yes this works. It is written in Note section of my original post. But question is how to make serializable IDictionary<Enum, string> data member.

Comment: ah sorry, try placing the [KnownType(typeof(MyEnum))] on the declaration for public enum MyEnum, just a guess